# Why does my java timer stop after seemingly random number of iterations?

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to create a simple java program that will run indefinitely and output a number every second. I believe my code here should do this; however, it stops after the variable i gets to either 2, 3 or 4. Randomly. Most of the time it hits 3. I do not think that the program stopping is based on i at all, but something i'm overlooking perhaps.

All this program needs to do is spit out the second count using a timer. I feel like my code might be a little over complicated so please let me know if i'm making it too hard.

```
package testing;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class driver {

    static int delay = 1000; //milliseconds 
    private Timer timer;
    int i = 0;
    public driver(){
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  System.out.println(i);
                  i++;
              }
          };
        timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new driver();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478505/why-timer-does-not-work-if-we-do-not-generate-a-window?rq=1

Comment: That is really interesting. I never would have thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is just right in your program, but one.

Your program starts (from main() obviously), which starts the timer, timer method initiates the process of displaying time/number every second, and after that, **the main thread dies!** resulting in completion of program execution.

So to avoid this you simply can keep main thread busy.

Here's the simplest way :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                driver d = new driver();
            }
        });
        for(;;); // <-- **Check this out :D**
    }
```

Comment: Good explanation! I actually was typing almost the exact same thing when the "1 New Question" icon came up haha! Beat me to it :P

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes total sense now. (And program works!)

Comment: One question though, did you name the new driver for any reason?

Comment: yeah.. ide was throwing warning :) (No need though)